# How to style react-table header on sorting

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-table

Is there any way to change the background color selected header in [react-table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme).
for example: below image, if I click on ID the id should change the background color to red.

I tried all the possibilities to change the background color on selection.

**css**

```
.ReactTable .rt-th  {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 0px;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding: 7px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition-property: width, min-width, padding, opacity;
    background: green;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried background-color?

Comment: @TyKroll yes I did. I want to change the background color to red when the header is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the above about using state to toggle the className. Below is the javascript, css and html that I would use in a bare bones example. The isActive property is set to false and then toggles the value with the handleClick method.

```
class Application extends React.Component {

constructor (props) {
super (props);
    this.state = { isActive:false }
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick () {
this.state.isActive ? this.setState({ isActive: false }) : this.setState({ 
isActive: true })
}

render() {
return <div>
  <div onClick={this.handleClick} className = { this.state.isActive ? "red" : "green"} > Background Color </div>
</div>;
}}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The css is rather straight forward.

```
.red 
background-color: red 

.green 
background-color: green
```

And html

```
<div id="app"></app>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about set state active and check the condition when render component?

Comment: can u throw me one example, please

Comment: I agree with this. Use state and do style={{ backgroundColor: isClicked ? 'red' : 'green' }}